# Query data displays locally in MySQL, but query in PHP is blank

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database that I am using to store the temperature of my pool and outside temperature every 10 to 30 minutes.  The issue I am having is with the code that I have I can run the query locally in MySQL and it works just fine.  But when I have the same query in PHP it gives me a blank page.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "xxxx";
$dbpass = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "pool_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die("Error " .mysqli_error($conn));


$sql = "SELECT * FROM tempLog ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error " .mysqli_error());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)); {
 ?>
<p><?php echo $row['poolTemp'];?></p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: white page of death turn on error reporting and display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this line, the semi-colon:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)); {
                                          ^ end of statement character
```

It just kills it right there and will fail silently, in turn giving you a blank screen; **remove it**.

- It is a valid character which will not throw an error. Therefore using error reporting is futile.

---

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> *As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.*

- The keyword here being "terminated".

---

- Also make sure you've in fact a row called "poolTemp" for `$row['poolTemp']`.

---

**My own tests:**

[blank screen] - with semi-colon

```
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; 

echo "<hr>";

$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql));{
                                   // ^ with semi-colon

echo $row['col1'] . " " . $row['col2'] . "<br>";

}

 mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

[results successfully shown] - without semi-colon

```
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; 

echo "<hr>";

$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                                   // ^ no semi-colon

echo $row['col1'] . " " . $row['col2'] . "<br>";

}

 mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_row`.  Also for bonus points, do yourself a favor and `echo` the paragraph markup so you can avoid breaking up all of the code.